# Access script variable by the string of it's name unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, types

My scene contains two objects - the first is the DataHolder object which contains a simple script with a single integer, which I've set to 5 in the editor.  The second is the DataReader class, which I want to use to access the value of "x" from the script assigned to DataHolder.

Importantly, in the DataReader class, I only have a reference to the Data script and the string of the variable that I want.  In particular, I am not looking for an answer like "dataScript.x", because the particular property name I'm looking for is going to be chosen by the user, so I can't hardcode it like that.

[My Scene]

[image: My Scene]

[Data Holder Object]

[image: Data Holder Object]

[Data Reader Object]

[image: Data Reader Object]

This is the code in the Data script assigned to DataHolder:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Data : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int x;
}
```

This is the code in the DataReader script assigned to DataReader.  I've assigned both the script and the propertyName in the editor, but I don't get the result I expect - I thought this would print out the value of x, but instead it prints out "Not found.":

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;
using System;

public class DataReader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEngine.Object script;
    public string propertyName;

    void Start(){
        Type scriptClass = script.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = scriptClass.GetProperties();
        bool found = false;
        foreach(var property in properties){
            if(property.Name == propertyName){
                Debug.Log("The value was: " + property.GetValue(script).ToString());
                found = true;
            }
            else{
            }
        }
        if(!found){
            Debug.Log("Not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I access the value of x from the Data script from DataReader, keeping in mind that I am really looking for the ability to access arbitrarily named fields from Data by the string of their name?

Comment: I believe you neeed the `scripClass.GetFields()` method not `GetProperties()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class DataReader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEngine.Object script;
    public string propertyName;

    void Start()
    {
        Type scriptClass = script.GetType();
        FieldInfo[] fields = scriptClass.GetFields();
        bool found = false;
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            if (field.Name == propertyName)
            {
                Debug.Log("The value was: " + field.GetValue(script).ToString());
                found = true;
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            Debug.Log("Not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

Fields are variables that store data, properties are members that provide read, write or compute for a private fields. It is easy to get them confused. Depending on what you want to do with this tool, I would also look into [BindingFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=net-5.0).